# Regex with strings: pairs of letters that occur twice

Tags: python, regex, string, list

How would you find pairs of letters that occur twice in a string using regex with Python?

I want to iterate through a list of strings, find the ones that have repeating pairs of letters, and put them into a list. The letters don't need to be the same, the pair just has to repeat, though the letters can be the same.

Ex:
`xxhgfhdeifhjfrikfoixx` - this one has `xx` twice so I want to keep this string
`kwofhdbugktrkdidhdnbk` - this one would be kept as well, because `hd` is repeated

The best I got was to find the pairs: `([a-z][a-z])\1|([a-z])\2`

I need to find which strings have pairs that repeat.

Comment: Make the title more descriptive of your problem. And Regex always work on strings.

Comment: Maybe, [`(\w{2}).*?\1`](https://regex101.com/r/pR0zU2/1)

Comment: That's close, as far as I got with it. But I meant any pair that occurs at least twice. So hb or aa, anything, as long as the pair repeats. I shouldve been clearer on that.

Comment: Okay, update the question to add more details, input string, expected output and your attempts

Comment: What flavor regex?  What language? What have you tried?

Comment: I learned regex tonight so Im not sure on the differences. Im using Python,  and I tried many times, I just havent gotten it right. The best I got to was this: ([a-z][a-z])\1|([a-z])\2 which found all the pairs, it just didnt narrow it down to the ones that repeated in the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Regular Expression

```
(\w{2}).*?(\1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/yB3nX6/1

### Visualisation

[image: Visualisation]

### Code

#### Iterate over all matches

```
for match in re.finditer(r"(\w{2}).*?(\1)", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    # match start: match.start()
    # match end (exclusive): match.end()
    # matched text: match.group()
```

#### Get an array of all regex matches in string

```
result = re.findall(r"(\w{2}).*?(\1)", subject, re.IGNORECASE)
```

### Human Readable

```
# (\w{2}).*?(\1)
# 
# Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Regex syntax only
# 
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w{2})»
#    Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, any number, underscore) «\w{2}»
#       Exactly 2 times «{2}»
# Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\1)»
#    Match the same text that was most recently matched by capturing group number 1 (case insensitive; fail if the group did not participate in the match so far) «\1»
```

### Notes

You can switch out `\w` for `[a-z]` if you want to be specific about only accepting `a-z` characters.